# Determining with remarkable accuracy birthplace of an American based on his pronunciation of a few words -- still possible?

Tags: accent, geolinguistics

Probably 40 or more years ago, I saw a professor of perhaps linguistic pick random members of a live tv audience, ask them to pronounce just a few words in English and I believe each time, guess the place of birth with great specificity. I don't mean state or large city -- almost any American could have said, You're from Brooklyn or Boston hearing in the latter case how the word "large" was pronounced -- in 1970, Bostonians really spoke so differently that communication could be difficult. (I mention "large" specifically because a story from an acquaintance of his friend asking for a large milk and pronouncing the "r" -- the waitress grew frustrated asking if he wanted an "orange milk" until he pronounced it as "lahhge" as Bobby Kennedy would have.)

I mean the professor could actually localize it to a city or town within iirc 30 miles from the actual place of birth. This of course relies upon the person remaining as an adult close  to where he had learned to speak and of course not moving from his birthplace before learning to speak/acquiring the local accent.

The professor sure seemed to do well, amazing the audience. My question is, assuming this was not luck or some fakery in 1970, could it still be done in the USA today?

I suspect that people move too much nowadays for this to work very well anymore -- that alone would why a person whose family moved a few times during their childhood might have an accent that was influenced by each place they lived in as children. But perhaps that is false: maybe there is something about the accent of the place in which you first learned to speak that sticks with the person even if they moved a few times before the age of 12 or so.

But it is also my impression that regional accents are almost non-existent or at least rare.  Firstly, tv and radio must have a strong effect but a much bigger effect is as mentioned, people after ww2 moved much more frequently that prior to ww2.

I don't know if explaining why I think people move more today than pre-ww2 -- I certainly have noticed that in some places everyone is from another state. But a few reasons I can give for people moving and also its influence on the fading of regional accents is primarily how much easier it became after the national highway system was built. Another thing, which occurred decades after the end of WW2 was the advent of cheaper long distance. Prior to that, how would one conduct a remote job search? WW2 was unique in that the demand for labor in some areas was so great that it was not a gamble to leave an agricultural job in the South and take a bus to Los Angeles where plants for building airplanes needed every worker. (This was described in the book Devil in a Blue Dress by Mosley.) Oak Ridge attracted also workers from various locations -- the government sent recruiters all over the USA to offer bus tickets and jobs.

**So the question again is, could the professor perform this same feat today or have accents eroded to the point where this is not possible, with an additional factor being a lot more mobility?**

Comment: [Henry Lee Smith Jr.](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=53848) is the linguist. But even when he did it, it was not common for even trained linguists to be able to do what he did. And he did do it, and he was accurate. He was surprised others didn't do it. Charles Ferguson once told me that when he was in an office with Smith, Smith asked him to give something to the secretary from Iowa. Ferguson had no idea who he meant, and Smith expressed surprise that it wasn't obvious to Ferguson, a famous linguist. Today, with so much TV and moving, I'd doubt it was still possible.

Comment: thanks. i am surprised there was just one person also but as u seem to agree, since it would not be possible anymore, no one else was motivated to learn the technique. i do not know if doing the same sort of thing would have been useful in interrogation during ww2 with pows but if you suspected an infiltrator who had only learned english in germany i bet smith cd have detected this.

Comment: It's not a technique, it's just precise and continuing observation of speech characteristics, coupled with encyclopedic knowledge of local speech variations in the US. This is what sociolinguists do.

Comment: @jlawler: I do not know why the word "technique" is not used aptly to describe what Smith did, but okay. Anyway, if you would post your comments as an answer, I would accept it. While the question seemed to be about whether accents no longer exist enough for this to be done today, I would have asked who the person was if I had thought someone knew -- it just seemed like a quirky "act" now faded into obscurity, interesting to learn the details you provided.

Comment: Smith made a movie, which is probly around somewhere on the web; it was about phonetics, which is as close as one can get to a "technique".